# Azure AppGW outbound IPs

Tags: azure

I have 2 VMs in availability set on Azure behind Application Gateway.

These VMs desn't have public ip address associated to the nic and need to send data to external servers that accept connection only from ips in white list.

Is it possible to assign the same static oubound ip address to these 2 VMs in backend pool and/or use application gateway as a NAT?

Comment: For this scenario I've resolve assigning a static ip at both VMs, but in another scenario I'veadopt a LB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give your VMs a static outbound IP you have three options, none of which relate to app gateway:

- Give the VMs a static IP, this will then be used for outbound traffic
- Attach the VMs to a load balancer with a public IP, they will then use this IP (you don’t actually need to do any load balancing or open up connections through the LB)
- Deploy an Azure Firewall and route outbound traffic through that. This will use the IP of the firewall.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do NAT in application gateway as it works on layer 7 it only supports on HTTP and HTTPS. For NAT use Azure Load Balancer